# Installing packages using anaconda

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, anaconda

I am trying to install scrapy and pandas using anaconda on my windows computer, but I am running into issues. I am sure I installed both packages correctly. I tried using both the anaconda navigator, pip, and a conda command. These do successfully install in my environment, as I can see these in my installed packages in anaconda. However, when I try running a simple scraping script, I get a ModuleNotFoundErrors for every package. I think it may have to do with the versions of python I have installed, but I'm not sure. I have python 3.8 installed.

Comment: Make sure you are in the correct environment.

Comment: Have you read the conda documentation? There are a bunch of tutorials.

Comment: I am almost positive I am in the correct environment. I followed the Anaconda documentation for installing scrapy and panda exactly.

Comment: Scrapy is not available for Python 3.8 on Conda Forge at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

When using anaconda, you will need to create an environment:

```
conda create -n <given name> python=3.7
```

then activate the environment:

```
source activate <given name>
```

Now go ahead and install packages using pip.

Comment: I did this, but I still get the same error. I am working in my environment

Comment: Its just the import statement. The import statement is just: import pandas